# some kotlin library attached to the project where compile with newer kotlin compiler and it can't be read... No update found

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Hi here I am try a payment project using Amazon Payment Services Android SDK. Here I am successfully done the payment functionality and it's works well. After implementing into main projects I got following issue.

**some kotlin library attached to the project where compile with newer kotlin compiler and it can't be read... No update found**

[image]

In My Gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.6.0"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://android-sdk.payfort.com" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

In Module

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.android.paymentdemoapp"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 31
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
multiDexEnabled true

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    implementation("com.amazon:fortpayment:+:release@aar"){
        transitive = true
    }
}
```

I'm modifying the kotlin version(1.6.10 to 1.4.32) and 'build:gradle:4.1.0' to 4.1.2 clean and rebuild the project I got the following issue...

```
e: /Users/raja/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2a57ced0732a783c670dc97c999acc46/jetified-core-ktx-1.8.0-alpha03-api.jar!/META-INF/core-ktx_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.2.
```

I'm tried to configure the kotlin version and Gradle build version different way but there is no use. Anyone please help me to fix this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: removed the maven url then Added a deviceprint-lib-release-2.3.2.aar file into lib folder... Now the issue are fixed....

Comment: I currently have this same issue and this solution doesn't work.

Comment: make sure the android-sdk.payfort.com lib latest version. Remove jcenter() in your build.gradle. Also you have to check the gradle-wrapper.properties "distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6_above_version". These thing will help to resolve the problem.